# how to recover partition table in external hard disk?

Tags: data-recovery, partition-table

I have an external hard disk plugged into `/dev/sdb`. This external hard disk is "Seagate Backup slim plus".

When I plug it in I get an error, "cannot open device" (both in windows or ubuntu GUI). `fschk` tells me the superblock is invalid and my partition table is not able to read.

So, can anyone help me to recover the partition table? because data is present in the external hard disk as I see with `test-disk`/`ddrescue` utility.

I use ubuntu most of the time of my life.

- When running `fsck`, I got below output

  ```
  $ fsck /dev/sdb

  fsck from util-linux 2.34
  e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
  ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
  fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
  fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

  The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
  filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
  filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
  is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
      e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
   or
      e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

  Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
  ```
- Then I found about `ddrescue`, and I understood, it will recover the data in a mapfile image which then can be loaded into an empty disk. I don't have an empty disk right now with sufficient storage, so I tried the `test-disk` utility.
- `test-disk` detected/analysed the partition and also gave an option to write partition file. but it says I need to reboot the system. I tried replugging my external-disk again but its still unreadable.
  (I have never used `test-disk` utility before).
- Partition information

  ```
  $ fdisk -l /dev/sdb

  Disk model: BUP Slim SL     
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x23cfdbc0

  Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
  /dev/sdb1  *     2048 3907024895 3907022848  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ```

Comment: You don't e2fsck on the whole disk, but the partition ( /dev/sdb1 ).

Comment: e2fsck also gives the same error as fsck output, given in the question @psusi

Comment: I didn't say you should use `e2fsck` instead of `fsck` ( which just runs `e2fsck` ).... I said you ran it on the wrong device.